# If statement return wrong value

Tags: php

I have a strange problem, a statement works correct on a test server but when I upload it to a live server I get an error.

My problem is as follows, I return a true or false depending on the number of rows of a query,  I have tested the query and seem to have a problem

```
$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
//$row for this example equals zero (0)
return ($row > 0) ? false : true;
```

It returns true, I am thinking maybe I should use an if statement, but I want to find out why this is returning true and it should return false;

Thank you in advance

Comment: What sort of debugging have you done?  Is there a problem with the query itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't entirely understand your question, but I'm going to take a shot in the dark here and say that you've got the return values the wrong way around in your ternary operator.

Try this:

```
return ($row > 0) ? true : false;
```

You can improve this even more so by doing:

```
return ($row > 0);
```

For reference, a ternary operator is the equivalent of writing:

```
if($row > 0)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

So there's no need to rewrite it to an `if()` statement.

Comment: .. or just `return $row > 0;`

Comment: or simply `return $row > 0`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, ideally it should return false if rows are greater than 0. Before saving any data I check if the value exist and if it does it returns false.

Comment: BenM thanks for the information, I ended up using return ($row < 0); and it is working. You led me in the right direction thanks. I wanted to return false if row is greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the ternary. just do this:

`return ($row > 0);`

You're already getting the Boolean from the result. No need to complicate it.